# fault handler (kernel) goes back to the thread does the process terminate

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have a question about internal part of the kernel, was not able to find much anymore.
If the fault handler (kernel) goes back to the thread that caused it, would the thread's process terminate? Or does this only happen if certain faults occur? Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean by "go back to"?

Comment: @NateEldredge As in return to the thread

Comment: Normally if an exception handler returns, the faulting instruction is restarted.  If the handler didn't do anything to correct whatever caused the fault, it will just fault again and you have an infinite loop.

Comment: Do you mean fault handler which handles incorrect **user** accesses or incorrect **kernel** accesses? The latter is not exposed to the driver/module programmer, the former is not specific to the Linux kernel internals but just a part of the interface to the user.